# Getting information from RadioButtons and Checkboxes

Tags: android

I have report which consists of 5 questions (there can be **only one answer** or **multiple choice answer**). Question are different for each report. So everytime I generate questions and answers as `RadioButtons` (one answer) or `CheckBoxes` (multiple choice answer)...But now I really don't know how to save those answers (I'd like to save to it as `_question_id`, `_answer_id`).

How can I assign good `_answer_id`, to `_question_id`...

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void saveAnswers() {
    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame); //or whatever your root control is
    loopQuestions(root);
}

private void loopQuestions(ViewGroup parent) {
    for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof RadioGroup ) {
            //Support for RadioGroups
            RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup)child;
            storeAnswer(radio.getId(), radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        }
        else if(child instanceof CheckBox) {
            //Support for checkboxes
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)child;
            int answer = cb.isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
            storeAnswer(cb.getId(), answer);
        }
        else {
            //Support for other controls
        }

        if(child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            //Nested Q&A
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)child;
            loopQuestions(group);
        }
    }
}

private void storeAnswer(int question, int answer) {
    //TODO: Store your answer to disk
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I have made sth similar by myself...I'm storing information <_question_ID, _answer_ID> into the Map collection when clicking the RadioButton or checking the CheckBox (when unchecking the information is deleted from Map)...When clicking saveAnwers, Map is saved into DB

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using RadioGroup for a group of mutually exclusive RadioButtons? Then:

```
radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()  // gets Id of clicked RadioButton within group
```

for CheckBox you must check for every button:

```
checkBox.isChecked()
```